# ExtJS 5: Initial ViewModel data not firing formula

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, viewmodel, extjs5

I have a ViewModel that contains some initial data... this initial data is based off of a global variable that I have created. In the ViewModel, I have a formula that does some logic based on the data set from the global variable. The interesting thing is, this formula does not fire when the ViewModel is created. I'm assuming this is because the Something.Test property does not exist, so the ViewModel internals have some smarts to not fire the method if that property does not exist.

If the property doesn't exist, how do I fire the formula anyway?  I know I could look for `Something` check to see if it has the property `Test`, but I'm curious why this example wouldn't work. Here's the [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/124t):

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        // Define global var Something
        Ext.define('Something', {
            singleton: true
        });
        Ext.define('MyViewModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
            alias: 'viewmodel.myView',
            data: {
                Something: window.Something
            },
            formulas: {
                testSomething: function(getter) {
                    console.log('here', getter('Something.Test'));
                    return getter('Something.Test');
                },
                myTitle: function(getter) {
                    return 'My Title';
                }
            }
        });
        Ext.define('MyView', {
            extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
            bind: {
                title: '{myTitle}'
            },
            viewModel: {
                type: 'myView'
            }
        });
        var view = Ext.create('MyView', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
        // This will fire the ViewModel formula
        //view.getViewModel().set('Something', window.Something);
        console.log(Something, window.Something)
    }
});
```

Comment: The view model is lazy - it won't be instantiated until something tries to access it. Try creating something that's bound to the view model in the view.

Comment: That's right... ok, see my updated code.  Let's say `Something.test` is not defined, but `Something` is... shouldn't my formula still fire?  I'm assuming it doesn't because of the ViewModel internals having some smarts to say the property doesn't exist, so it shouldn't fire.

Comment: Nope - the laziness continues to kick in. The ViewModel is now being instantiated, but the formula won't evaluate until it's asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can workout some logic to handle when Something.Test is not available, something like:

```
data: {
    Something: window.Something && window.Something.Test || {Test: null}
},
formulas: {
    testSomething: function(get) {
        var val = get('Something.Test');
        console.log('Test');
        return val;
    },
    myTitle: function(getter) {
        return 'My Title';
    }
}
```

Comment: Humm..thought that would work. Anyway, example updated.

Comment: I could've sworn I tried that... but yes, that'll work.  I just figured even though `Something` exists, but `Test` is technically undefined, the formula would still fire... guess I was wrong.  Thanks for clearing that up.